# mongodb keyerror even though field exists

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a mongodb collection friends and I run the code

```
for doc in friends.find():
    print doc
```

I get:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('519ccdb86383cf1444445a1c'), u'twitter_id': 609034617}
{u'_id': ObjectId('519ccdb86383cf1444445a1d'), u'twitter_id': 253090547}
{u'_id': ObjectId('519ccdb86383cf1444445a1e'), u'twitter_id': 146221326}
{u'_id': ObjectId('519ccdb86383cf1444445a1f'), u'twitter_id': 1267350151}
{u'_id': ObjectId('519ccdb86383cf1444445a20'), u'twitter_id': 8806112}
{u'_id': ObjectId('519ccdb86383cf1444445a21'), u'twitter_id': 82589355}
```

but if I do:

```
for doc in friends.find():
    print doc['twitter_id']
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\schatterjee\workspace\scorefollowback.py\application.py", line 65, in     <module>
    print doc['twitter_id']
KeyError: 'twitter_id'
```

Comment: inside the loop what type of object is `doc`?

Comment: @dm03514 offcourse JSON that is inside the mongodb collection

Comment: did you look? I don't think it is a JSON object, it might be a python dictionary.  What happens if you drop in a debugger in your loop and inspect each `doc`? Can you access attributes with `doc.twitter_id` what data, if any, is in the `doc` in the loop?

Comment: Which orm or driver are you using?

Comment: if I change twitter_id to twitterid it works. is it a problem with the underscore?

Comment: if its a dictionary should I convert it to JSON and then insert?

Comment: it is indeed a dictionary, you are right

Comment: If you change 'twitter_id' to u'twitter_id', does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps some of your documents don't have a twitter id. Here is an example shell session with good data:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> conn = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
>>> users = conn['test']['users']
>>> users.remove()
>>> users.insert({'twitter_id': '11111111'})
>>> users.insert({'twitter_id': '22222222'})
>>> for user in users.find():
    ...     print(user['twitter_id'])
    ... 
    11111111
    22222222
```

You might want to try using `$exists` to make sure the field is present like this: `Syntax: { field: { $exists: <boolean> } }`

```
for friend in friends.find({ twitter_id: { $exists: true } }):
    print(friend['twitter_id'])
```

Comment: I have the same problem, I have made sure the field exists and if i run the same query in a seperate process it is not throwing that error.